# Program using java.io that shows the content of a text file and every three lines the program stop reading, waiting to press Enter

Tags: java, file

I am doing a program in Java your text using java.io that shows the content of a text file and every three lines the program stop reading, waiting to press Enter. I dont know so much about programming, so i want to improve my code an my way to program reading your coments, this is the code:

```
package ficheros_ejercicio4;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Programa que muestra el contenido de un fichero y cada 23 líneas el fichero se parará 
 * hasta que el usuario pulse la tecla Intro
 * 
 * @author José A. Cruz
 */
public class ContinuaIntro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String seguir = "";
        File f = new File("continua.txt");
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linea;
            do {
                linea = br.readLine();
                if(linea != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
                linea=br.readLine();
                    if(linea != null) {
                    System.out.println(linea);
                    linea=br.readLine();
                        if(linea != null) {
                        System.out.println(linea);
                        System.out.println("Para continuar leyendo pulse la tecla Enter...");
                        linea=sc.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while(linea.equals(seguir));
            sc.close();
            br.close();
            
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move most of your code away from the `main` function for maintainability and testability.

Your variable names (`seguir`) should be in English, which is the de-facto language of programming; it's fine for your user interface text to be local.

You should have your stream resources in a `try`-with-resources or a `try`-`finally`.

This program is a rough clone of the `more` pager (and its much more complicated big sister, the `less` pager). There are features of those pagers you should emulate, mostly: after every page, you should be able to read a section of the file uninterrupted by `Para continuar` prompts. Stock Java does not make this easy. So long as you don't use third-party libraries, the best thing to do is probably just print your prompt once, and then never again. Rely on the return character from the user to feed the last line of the page. This way, the file will appear as it does on disk.

It's not necessary to close both a file reader and its associated buffered reader; only close the latter.

It's easy enough to make this a much more useful program by removing the hard-coded filename and accepting it as the first command-line parameter.

### Suggested

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static class Pager implements AutoCloseable {

        private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        private final BufferedReader reader;

        private final int blockSize;

        public Pager(String filename, int blockSize) throws FileNotFoundException {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(filename);
            reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            this.blockSize = blockSize;
        }

        public void run() throws IOException {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 1; i < blockSize; ++i) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) return;
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) return;
                System.out.print(line);

                in.nextLine();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Para continuar leyendo pulse la tecla Enter...");
        try (Pager pager = new Pager(args[0], 3)) {
            pager.run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation on why your loop implementation is an improvement would be a good idea, since I assume that was one of the main points of the exercise. Now this looks a bit like just rewriting without explanation.